# Why am I returning null when I am trying to obtain a process ID (pid) of a c language program in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb

While on Linux, inside `gdb`, I am trying to find the PID of this C program inside my designated directory.  However when I try to use command `(gdb) info inferior` I get the output:

```
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable        
* 1    <null>                                 /home/(cut because it showed personal name) /debug/example
```

The PID of the process should be next to `* 1` but it is just returning null?  I do not understand why.

I know the command `(gdb) print getpid()` can also retrieve the PID but it outputs:

```
No symbol "getpid" in current context.
```

Can someone help explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

There is no information because you presumably have not started to debug the program yet, and there is no child process.

Use `start` to begin debugging.

```
$ gdb example
Reading symbols from example...
(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable        
* 1    <null>                                 /path/to/example
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x113d: file example.c, line 5.
Starting program: /path/to/example 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at example.c:5
5       puts("Hello world.");
(gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable        
* 1    process 28506     1 (native)           /path/to/example 
(gdb)
```